# Embed play in a standard Java web-app?

Tags: java, scala, jakarta-ee, playframework

We have a webapp using standard JSP/servlets and packaged as a `war` file. This makes the app really portable. We can push it to any cloud supporting Java (such as AWS beanstalk). I believe Play 2.0 does not provide standalone `war` files.

However, I want to use some of Play's features such as web-socket servers without using Play.
So I was wondering if I can simply import a "play.jar" type file in my standard J2EE web-app and use it in "embedded mode" to run a web-socket server without having to fully run Play.

Answer (score 1):

Until Play 2.0 there was a built in war target.  It was removed for some reason but luckily a third party developed the Play2-War plugin: https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin

**Edit**

If you want a completely standalone distribution you can run the `play dist` task.  This will package up all the dependencies in a jar and provide a simple bash script to start it (or you can just use the command yourself).  You can even have it zip or tarball the resulting file for you.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist

If more broadly you want to include Play as a dependency other than the standard sbtplugin then MVN Repository has links to download the jar and will give you the code for your dependency manager of choice (maven, ivy, sbt, gradle etc...)

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.4.0-M1

Comment: I'm more interested to see if I can run Play in embedded mode in my standard Java (not necessarily J2EE) application without depending on a prior Play installation.